# Referencing an equation in the caption results in the error in the generated list of captions

Tags: captions

In my thesis, I generate a list of figures and their captions in the beginning of the work. However, there appears an error in the generated list (in the beginning of the document) when a caption contains a reference to an equation (but there is no error in the caption itself in the body of the work), e.g.

```
...maximize the objective (3.1 LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preambleSee...
```

How can I keep the reference and remove the error?

The error disappears in the list of figures when, as suggested, I use `\string\eqref{name}` to reference a figure. Yet in the caption in the body the reference number disappears, only displaying

```
“eqrefname
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code in question?

Comment: You may have to format the "short" caption using \string\ref.

Comment: `\ref` should be `\protect`ed when it is written to the `.aux` file. (John Kormylo is suggesting essentially the same thing.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo, amazing comment. This little trick answered my question.

Comment: And same for @GustavoMezzetti.

Comment: \protect is better.  You won't need a separate short caption that way.  Anyway, the point is that you don't want to expand \ref too soon.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Can you make an answer? Maybe adding that, with `hyperref`, adding `\protect` is not necessary before `\ref`, but it is still required in front of `\eqref`.

Comment: @egreg: Rethinking about this, I am not able to figure out what the actual problem was that the OP ran into.  An un`\protect`ed `\eqref` is of course expanded upon `\write`, and, without _hyperref_, the `\ref` it contains is expanded too, but this doesn’t produce any error.